# flowplayer load and unload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, flowplayer

I'm using a latest flowplayer, and i'ved created couple of buttons that provides video source from cdn. With the click event the player should load the video source dynamically. But for some reason flowplayer cant unload and load the source of video properly. Instead I get the following error

> html5: Video file not found

```
function flow(source) {
        jQuery("#flow").flowplayer().unload();
        jQuery("#flow").flowplayer().load(source);
    }
```

alternatively I've tried to re-init the flowplayer with every click, but sometime the initial video get loaded instead of the clicked video source. After couple of clicks the flowplayer also get stuck on loading screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/qAj8x/

Comment: Is there a particular browser you are using?  As they all played for me using Chrome

Comment: Worked for me in FireFox.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using chrome for this purpose then from [here](http://flowplayer.org/docs/known-issues.html) . Chrome and Flow Player dose not go well together.

1. Native fullscreen is supported in Chrome 15+, Safari 5.1+ and Firefox 14+ and others will use full browser window. In Firefox 9+ the fullscreen is disabled and needs to be manually enabled at about:config (full-screen-api.enabled;true).
2. Some Chrome versions have issues with playing MP4 content. Workaround: List a WEBM before the MP4 source and/or set preload="none" as video tag attribute.
3. Chrome gets stuck when trying to load the same video twice, even in two different tabs.